# Chrome extension act as a server (let other local scripts to communicate with the extension)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking into a way to make an external script to communicate with a Chrome extension. I want to allow a local app to send a request to the Chrome extension and get data.

Something like:
Python script -> send HTTP request to a local open port controlled by the Chrome Extension -> return JSON

In this sense, I considered modifying this web-server app, but the Chrome Apps API was discontinued (https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome).

Is there a functional way to open a socket, write to a file, etc., so the data gathered from the Chrome Extension can be shared with another script? I can do the inverse and let the Chrome extension send the data to the script in a scheduled way, but I would rather do the data gathering on demand.

Any recommendations are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Extensions have nativeMessaging API for that.

Comment: Thanks, however when using native messaging, the "starter" of the conversation is always the chrome extension, right? I haven't seen the possibility of making arbitrary calls to the extension from the python script.

Comment: The extension starts an intermediary app that relays all messages between the extension and the [previously running] main app.